# Why is this the derivative of $\frac{1}{\tan^{-1}x}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry

I don’t understand how the derivative of the said function is $-1(\frac{1}{(\tan^{-1} x)^2})(\frac{1}{1+x^2})$. I know the derivative of $\tan^{-1}x$ is $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ but I am at a loss on how the derivative of the given became like that.

Comment: chain rule to $\frac{1}{u}$ with $u=\tan^{-1}(x)$

Comment: I suggest to give a good reading to this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to know the Chain Rule which is used in getting the derivative of a composition of functions:

Given the function $f, g$, let $t = g(x)$. Then we have:

$$((f \circ g)(x))' = f'(t) \cdot g'(x)$$

So your function $f = \frac{1}{\arctan(x)}$, let $t = \arctan(x)$, we get:

$$ (\frac{1}{\arctan(x)})' = (\frac{1}{t})' \cdot (\arctan(x))'$$

$$= \frac{-1}{t^2} \frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

$$= \frac{-1}{\arctan^2(x)} \frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

You can also try this example to understand the Chain Rule:

$$(\frac{1}{1+x^3})' = ?$$

Let $t = 1+x^3$, then we have:

$$(\frac{1}{1+x^3})' = \frac{-1}{t^2} \cdot (1+x^3)'$$

$$= \frac{-1}{(1+x^3)^2} \cdot 3x^2$$

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{d}{dx}[\frac{1}{\tan^{-1}x}] = \frac{d}{dx}[f(g(x))] = g^{\prime}(x)f^{\prime}(g(x))$, where $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ and $g(x) = \tan^{-1}x$ ([chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule))

$g^{\prime}(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ and $f^{\prime}(x) = -\frac{1}{x^2}$

Thus,

$g^{\prime}(x)f^{\prime}(g(x)) = (\frac{1}{1+x^2})\cdot(-\frac{1}{(\tan^{-1}x)^2}) = -1(\frac{1}{(\tan^{-1} x)^2})(\frac{1}{1+x^2})$

I would suggest using an online derivative calculator when you get stuck. I would use [this](https://www.derivative-calculator.net/) since it gives a good amount of steps/explanation.